# Bounding expectation of switching stochastic process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> I am analyzing the behavior of an 1D stochastic dynamic system, where the state can vary randomly within a small magnitude. However, when the state deviates too much from zero, its expected magnitude will reduce to zero. I would like to see if the state will stay within some bound with high probability.

> Existing theory of stochastic control uses super-martingale inequality, which is not the case for such dynamic system. I am wonder whether there are any prior works on analyzing such dynamic system. I formalize my problem below:

Suppose I have an 1D, positive, continuous-state, discrete-time Markov chain $\{X_n|X_n\geq0\}$ that switches between two modes depending on two positive constants $C>0$ and $C'>0$ as follows:

$\bullet$ When $X_n\geq C$: We have $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|X_n\geq C]\leq X_n$.

$\bullet$ When $X_n<C$: We have $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|X_n<C]>X_n$ and $\text{Pr}(X_{n+1}>X_n+C'|X_n<C)=0$.

I am wondering whether we can upper bound the expectation as $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\leq\text{poly}(C,C')$.